# Insert Text at current position TINYMCE IE9

Tags: tinymce, internet-explorer-9

How to insert text into a tinyMce edtitor at the current position.
It works perfect in Chrome, FF, Safari, but in IE it always starts at the top of the textarea.
I currently do the following:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false, 'blabla this is tekst');
```

I tried with focus, other commands, nothing works :(.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for the help, but nothing worked. I found my own solution, and I felt like sharing this was needed, because I only found outdated solutions, that did not work :(.

The solution:

In your TinyMCE init add following code:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
// General options
        elements: elementid,
        setup: function (ed) {
            ed.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, e) {
                actualCaretPositionBookmark = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getBookmark();
            });
            ed.onClick.add(function (ed, e) {
                actualCaretPositionBookmark = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getBookmark();
            }); 
        }
```

Where "actualCaretPositionBookmark" is a global variable in javascript that can be accesed by all your javascript code

Then when you want to add text into your TinyMCE editor via javascript, add following code:

```
                if (tinymce.isIE) {
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.moveToBookmark(actualCaretPositionBookmark);
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false, 'My new text'); 

            }else {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('insertHTML',false, 'My new text'); 
            }
```

Comment: I have some strange behavior in tiny in IE9 because of onKeyUp and getBookmark(). Instead of **onKeyUp**, **onKeyPress** works better:)

Comment: you saved my time. Thanks..:)

Comment: Brilliant solution. I added the call to getBookmark within the addCommand method, meaning it automatically runs however the user initiates the action.  Saved me a lot of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach to solve your issue. When initializing tinymce set the setup parameter to the following (inside `tinyMCE.init({...})`

```
...
theme: "advanced",   // example param
plugins = 'code',    // example param
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {

        var dom = ed.dom;
        var doc = ed.getDoc();

        tinymce.dom.Event.add(doc, 'blur', function(e) {
            // onBlur you save your caret position
            actual_caret_position_bookmark = tinymce.get('your_editor_id').selection.getBookmark(2, true);
        });
    });
},
cleanup: true,      // example param
...
```

now, you need to reset the tinymce caret position just before you insert the new content using the mceInsertContent command:

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id').selection.moveToBookmark(actual_caret_position_bookmark);
```

Comment: tinymce.get('your_editor_id').selection.getBookmark(2, true) is always undifiend, (I use the correct id).
Also if I use inymce.activeEditor.selection.getBookmark(2, true) the item is undefined. Any Id,

Comment: you will need to have a selection by then of course (a caret inside the editor in order to get a valid bookmark)

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple editors in the same page you can try this

```js
tinymce.get('content_id').execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'content to be inserted');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [DEMO](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/22caab/5) Open this link in IE9

Place cursor at the desired location in the textarea and then click on the last icon(red cross) in third row in tinyMCE.

Hope it helps!! :)

As per your comment, click on the button(Click Me) which is outside the tinymce editor.
Check the [DEMO](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/22caab/7) again.

Comment: It works from the toolbar button, but my button is not in TinyMce, it is a self made sidebar, when I fire the event from there, the new content is always written on top of the editor
The reason is that when I click the external button, the cursor in IE is gone, and it just adds the content to the editor ,i need to save the cursor pos?

Comment: Try clicking next to the button and then onto the button in IE9

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue some while ago, I have a plugin using a modal popup and also use the same method described above. :

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false, 'blabla this is tekst');
```

In IE9 the text is inserted in the top. The problem with playing with the caret is that, in my case, certain strange things happened (The backspace delete breaks), so I checked the code for the smileys plugin embedded inside the tinyMCE distribution that I'm using. the solution I found was to use the TinyMCEPopup object instead, like this:

```
tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'blabla this is tekst');
```

Regards.