# How to incorporate change event in tinymce?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tinymce

I am trying to use [angular2-tinymce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-tinymce) library in my project. I have successfully integrated **tinymce** in my module. But i could not trigger any callback for change event when any changes happened in the tinymce editor.

```
// in add-progress-note.module.ts file
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AddProgressNotePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AddProgressNotePage),
    TinymceModule.withConfig({
      menubar: false,
      plugins: ['textcolor'],
      toolbar: 'forecolor',
      resize: false,
      statusbar: false
    })
  ]
})

// in add-progress-note.html file           
<ion-row class="note-editor" id="noteArea">
            <app-tinymce class="note-input-textarea" [(ngModel)]='noteText' (change)="onChangeNote()"></app-tinymce>
</ion-row>

// in add-progress-note.ts file
  onChangeNote(): void {
    console.log(this.noteText);
  }
```

My onChangeNote did not fire.

How to trigger a callback event for any change event in tinymce editor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `ngModel`, you can easily use `ngModelChange` instead of `change`.

```
<app-tinymce class="note-input-textarea" [(ngModel)]='noteText' (ngModelChange)="onChangeNote()"></app-tinymce>
```

Comment: can i append text where the cursor is using this approach in tinymce editor?

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521392/using-tinymce-in-angular2-project and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393892/inserting-text-in-tinymce-editor-where-the-cursor-is help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i use that and it's work, thanks **Suraj Rao**

html :

```html
<editor [(ngModel)]="html" [init]="init" (ngModelChange)="removeColor($event)"></editor>
```

TS :

```
    public removeColor(value) {
        this.html = value.replace(/color(.*?);/i, '');;
    }
```