# How to insert text in TinyMCE Editor where the cursor is?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tinymce

I am trying to use [angular2-tinymce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-tinymce) library in my project. I have successfully integrated **tinymce** in my module. But i could not find any way to insert text from where the cursor is in the tinymce editor.

```
// in add-progress-note.module.ts file
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AddProgressNotePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AddProgressNotePage),
    TinymceModule.withConfig({
      menubar: false,
      plugins: ['textcolor'],
      toolbar: 'forecolor',
      resize: false,
      statusbar: false
    })
  ]
})

// in add-progress-note.html file           
<ion-row class="note-editor" id="noteArea">
            <app-tinymce class="note-input-textarea" [(ngModel)]='noteText' (ngModelChange)="onChangeNote()"></app-tinymce>
</ion-row>

// in add-progress-note.ts file
  onChangeNote(): void {
    console.log(this.noteText);
  }
```

I have see these links: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393892/inserting-text-in-tinymce-editor-where-the-cursor-is) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521392/using-tinymce-in-angular2-project). But i could not write the callback in **setup** config of **TinymceModule**

How to incorporate text inserting from cursor in tinymce editor in my code?

Comment: Are you trying to do this via a toolbar button?  A menu?  Something else?  What would trigger this insertion?

Comment: I have a button in my page just below tinymce editor. And when i will click on the button, i will generate a text and i would like to append this text in the tinymce editor just where the cursor is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could insert text from cursor position in tinymce editor using below approach:

```
     this.tinyMce.editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'text');
```